# Adding an element to the beginning of the array php

Tags: php

Is there a built-in php function or an easy way to insert an element to the beginning of an array?

Something Like:

```
$matches = Array("apples", "oranges");
insert_to_beginning($matches, "peach");
```

Contents:

```
$matches[0] = peach
$matches[1] = apples
$matches[2] = oranges
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`array_unshift`](http://php.net/array_unshift) is the function you're looking for.

```
array_unshift($matches, "peach");
```

Comment: @zerkms: Hey, I provided a non-locale-specific link! (Yeah, I know you were first. Sigh.)

Answer (score 5):

```
array_unshift($matches, 'peach');
```

http://nz.php.net/array_unshift

Comment: Hm... life just isn't fair sometimes! :|